# Toggle Font Awesome icons on click w/ accordion feature

Tags: jquery, toggle, accordion, font-awesome

I have almost no experience with jQuery but I've seen it's fairly simple to achieve a result like I want. The span tag in the panel heading shows a font awesome right-facing caret, and I would like it to toggle to a down-facing caret when clicked (when the accordion will trigger). There's like 12 of these accordion categories on the page so I need it to work for all instances of the caret icon.

```
<div class="panel-group">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a href="#category" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#difcategory">
                <span class="icon-caret-right"></span> Title 
            </a>
        </h4>
    </div>

    <div id="category" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">Accordion info</div><!-- end panel-body -->
    </div><!-- end panel-collapse collapse -->
</div><!-- end panel-group -->
```

Comment: Have you made an effort? SO isn't a free freelancer service. :-) That said, you may be able to do it with CSS by modifying the pseudo-element that the icon classes use. Target the `in` class on the ancestor accordion element.

Comment: I did make an effort though I realize my question doesn't accurately display it haha. I was looking at a lot of already answered questions and I saw jQuery was useful for what I wanted (this code in particular - http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/f72FY/2/) but I wasn't sure how it would translate when I have a lot of specific divs that are part of the development site's coding and not my own. I never thought of doing it through CSS, though, so thank you - I'm going to look into it!

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this.

```
<a class="toggle-me"><span></span>Title</a>

.panel-heading .toggle-me:before {
    font-family: 'FontAwesome'; 
    content: "\f078";        
    color: #303030;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-right: 10px;      
}

.panel-heading .toggle-me.collapsed:before {
    content: "\f054";   
}
```

Comment: This is essentially what I was describing in my comment above. Here's the start of a fiddle, though the FA file is missing. http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/x2bu8gur/

Comment: Yeah, saw your comment edit when posting. It's a start, please update your Fiddle with my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using the class based approach with font awesome you can change the class that is responsible for showing the icon.

```
$('#category').on('click' function() {
  var $icon = $(this).find('span');
  if ($icon.hasClass('icon-caret-right')) {
    $icon.removeClass('icon-caret-right').addClass('icon-caret-down');
  } else {
    $icon.addClass('icon-caret-right').removeClass('icon-caret-down');
  }
  // code to do accordion
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put both icons in the layout and define the visible one using CSS.

```
<div class="panel-group">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a href="#category" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#difcategory">
                <span class="icon-caret-right"></span><span class="icon-caret-down"></span> Title 
            </a>
        </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="category" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">Accordion info</div><!-- end panel-body -->
    </div><!-- end panel-collapse collapse -->
</div><!-- end panel-group -->

.panel-title a .icon-caret-right
{
    display: block;
}
.panel-title a .icon-caret-down
{
    display: none;
}
.panel-title a.collapsed .icon-caret-right
{
    display: none;
}
.panel-title a.collapsed .icon-caret-down
{
    display: block;
}
```